# Autofilter with more than 3 criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the following code to autofilter a column using more than 3 criteria - however, it is saying the "Autofilter method of range class failed"

This code looked to be working on another SO post.

Can anyone assist?

Thanks

```
Public Sub autofilter2()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wsOut As Worksheet
Dim a As String

Dim b As String
Dim c As String

Set ws = Worksheets("Raw Data")
'AutoFilterMode = False
a = Cells(69, 6).Value
b = Cells(69, 7).Value
c = Cells(69, 8).Value


ws.Range("A:bk").autofilter field:=64, _
Criteria1:=Array(a, b, c), _
Operator:=xlFilterValues



End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*64* is beyond column **BK**.  The max you can have is *63*